# POD Template class with optional members

Tags: c++, templates

I am looking for a way to optionally include members of a c++ class to generate POD structs. I found that this works fairly well, but is nonstandard:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int v, int n, int t>
struct Point
{
    int vertex[v];
    float normal[n];
    double texcoord[t];
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << (sizeof (Point<0,0,1>)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (sizeof (Point<1,0,1>)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (sizeof (Point<1,1,2>)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (sizeof (Point<0,0,0>)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So Point<1,0,0> would only contain a vertex (the int type will actually be a vector3 type in practice), and so on.  The main reason for this is to easily support interleaved arrays for OpenGL.

Comment: What makes you think that this works? What compiler do you use? In `gcc`, there's an extention and you may write `int x[0]` and this does not mean, that `x` does not exist. For reference: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: Well, it does mean that, it takes no space and it will point to the place after the previous member, correct? I haven't actually put this to work yet, but it seems to work given the test above. I thought it was a good way to exposit the question, though.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <unsigned int v, unsigned int n, unsigned int t>
struct Point
{
    int data[v + n + t];

    template <unsigned int i>
    typename std::enable_if<(i < v), int &>::type
    vertex() { return data[i]; }

    template <unsigned int i>
    typename std::enable_if<(i < v + n), int &>::type
    normal() { return data[v + i]; }

    template <unsigned int i>
    typename std::enable_if<(i < v + n + t), int &>::type
    texcoord() { return data[v + n + i]; }
};
```

Usage:

```
Point<1,1,2> p;
p.vertex<0>() = 50;
```

Comment: Unfortunately they won't all be ints. One could be a vector3, one could be a vector2, etc.  I'll clarify the question.  This looks promising, though.

Comment: @solinent: What about an array of unions as the underlying construct?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Slight typo for `vertex()`, you want `return data[i]`.

Comment: @user315052: Thanks. I think I copy/pasted something wrong. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

`std::array<T, 0>` is valid, unlike `T[0]` and really is a better solution all around. Unfortunately, and since this is only available for C++11, I can't figure out if its Boost namesake `boost::array` also has such support.

It is also possible to write an `array`-like helper yourself.

Comment: +1, as this is a very nice suggestion, but it will not be a POD, as the OP requested.

Comment: But `array<T, 0>` would probably cause unnecessary bloat, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user315052 I suspect that by virtue of `std::array<T, N>` being an aggregate, it is a POD iff `T` is (I don't have the time to double-check though).

Comment: I don't specifically need POD, but I need to ensure the data is arranged contiguously and be able to send it to OGL as-is. So perhaps s

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you would need specializations.

**Edit:** Matched with new question requirement of different type per array. Made template arguments unsigned though.

```
template <> struct Point<0, 0, 0> {};
template <unsigned v> struct Point<v, 0, 0> { int vertex[v]; };
template <unsigned n> struct Point<0, n, 0> { float normal[n]; };
template <unsigned t> struct Point<0, 0, t> { double texcoord[t]; };
template <unsigned v, unsigned n> struct Point<v, n, 0> {
    int vertex[v];
    float normal[n];
};
template <unsigned v, unsigned t> struct Point<v, 0, t> {
    int vertex[v];
    double texcoord[t];
};
template <unsigned n, unsigned t> struct Point<0, n, t> {
    float normal[n];
    double texcoord[t];
};
```

Each specialization leaves out the associated array when its corresponding template parameter has value `0`. For three items as shown, the enumeration of specializations is not overly large, and provides exactly the same syntax for accessing the elements as your original post but using standard C++ constructs.

Extending this technique beyond 3 arrays would be cumbersome. However, it could be managed with a script to generate the specializations for you.